# how to make infinite loop in android?

Tags: android, infinite-loop

I d like to make a `while(true)` in my code but ,when i run, i don t see anything:
I've tried with `AsyncTask` but i think that a infinite loop it's too heavy.

```
public class openActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ArrayList<String> myArraylist = new Arraylist<> ();
 CustomAdapter myAdapter;
 ListView list;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     setContentView(R.layout.myActivity);
     list = findViewById(R.id.myList);
     try {
         while (true) {
             Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myUrl).get;
             //here i get info i need
             //add that info to myArraylist
             myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myArraylist);
             list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
             myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             while (myArrayList.get(0).equals(myArraylist.get(0))) {
                 Thread.sleep(900000);
             }
         }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.getLocalizeMessage()
     }
 }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this "             while (myArrayList.get(0).equals(myArraylist.get(0))) {
                 Thread.sleep(900000);
             }
"

Comment: you cannot make it in the onCreate method, as it blocks the main thread, which is the UI thread. I suggest you take a look here for more info. https://developer.android.com/guide/background/

Comment: I think a better question for this is why would you want to do that? not the best of ideas.

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim i need to take all info from my WebSite, 
but I would like to continue to take only the new posts. So in the while I would say that until the first element of the arraylist is the same, pause the scraping

Comment: @peshkira, yes i know that i can t make it in the onCreate, i ve tried to make in Asyntask but don  t work.. I hope in a suggestion ;)

Comment: @DroiDev because i need.. but if you have a better idea, I listen to you with pleasure

Comment: can you debug and see while setting adapter . arraylist is having data ?

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim, yes, in arraylist i add first data... the adapter work without while(true)

Comment: @AbubakkerMoallim i did simply adding a button that updates based on the condition... same result, few resources!
thanks anyway for the availability =)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is blocking the UI thread. To perform a periodic task you should use a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService).

Also, avoid recreating the adapter on every iteration. Update the existing data and use [DiffUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) to notify the changes.

Answer (score 1):

or you can try this :

```
myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myArraylist);
list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
getData();

public void getData(){
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myUrl).get;
         //here i get info i need
         //add that info to myArraylist
         myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         getData()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work if it is posted on the main thread. 

From the docs: The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached. The time-base is uptimeMillis(). Time spent in deep sleep will add an additional delay to execution.

Comment: doesn t work... nothing appears on the listview.. thanks anyway

Comment: the problem is that the listview is empty already from the beginning,instead the listview with the first results should give it anyway

Comment: yes, i tried... doesn t work... i don t know how to do :'(

Comment: Are you sure "Document doc = Jsoup.connect(myUrl).get"  is synchronous and not asynchronous